# Install libopencv-dev 32bit on 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, apt, 64-bit, opencv

I've already installed the 64bit version of the package `libopencv-dev` and want now to install the 32bit version.

I tried the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev:i386
```

but got the following error message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libopencv-dev:i386:
   Depends: libopencv-core-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-ml-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-imgproc-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-video-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-gpu-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-calib3d-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-flann-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-features2d-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev:i386 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a conflict with the 64bit version?

Comment: The error message is quite self explanatory: `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: @hbdgaf That's only self-explanatory to someone deeply familiar with APT.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there may be conflicts in cases such as this. Not all packages are fully Multi-Arch capable or supported. There are more packages in newer versions of Ubuntu which are, but many still have not been converted to Multi-Arch.

Comment: I think it's more related to pinning and holding multi-arch packages than it is to an unconverted package.  Lots of people seem to run in to problems with multi-arch, but I run latest ppas for everything i386 compat related and everything seems to work for me.  I think it's more related to stale packages being pinned.

Comment: @hbdgaf Interesting, could you write something about this? Is actually quite a mess installing skype, AndroidSDK and whatnot in Ubuntu 64bits (I'm actually thinking on installing Ubuntu myself and see "what's up", just not around to actually do it) so a guide post to correctly set up multiarch support so people might follow and then ask if something is still messed up, or some obscure element is acting up.

Comment: @hbdgaf PPAs may also have more stuff converted. Saying you run all the PPAs for all the latest stuff, isn't helpful. You don't need to make an assumption that something is pinned on the asker's system.

Comment: @Braiam There is nothing to "set up" with multi-arch. Simply install the latest version of Ubuntu, and it automatically has the best support for multi-arch. However, as I said in my answer, not everything is converted, and depending on what you are trying to install, this can present issues.

Comment: @dobey - When I say ppa latest, I mean for things that people often complain about, like wine.  Running a base install and the ppa for any troublesome app with no pinning, I haven't had any problems.  I think that explains what I meant.